# Let $G=N\rtimes H$ and the conjugacy action of $H$ on $N$ divide $N$ in two orbits. Show $N$ is abelian (and more).

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-actions, semidirect-product

Given a finite group $G$, $N \trianglelefteq G$, and $H \leq G$, such that $G$ is the inner semidirect product of $N$ and $H$, and knowing that the conjugacy action of $H$ on $N$ divides $N$ in two orbits, prove that:

1. There exists a prime $p$ such that any nontrivial element of $N$ has order $p$
2. $N$ is abelian
3. It doesn't exist $M \trianglelefteq G$ nontrivial and properly contained in $N$.

My solution for $(1)$:
I know that $N$ is divided in two orbits, and since there's one orbit that contains only $1_G$, all the elements $n\in N:n \neq 1_G$ are in the same orbit, meaning that they all have the same order, since the action is the conjungancy one. It follows that the order of $N$ must be $p^\alpha$, $p$ prime. I've been stuck for some time on $(2)$ and $(3)$ though, so any hint would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I would do 3 first, asking what the orbit of an element of $M$ would look like. For 2, think about nontrivial normal subgroups of $p$-groups.

Comment: There must be a missing hypothesis that $G$ is finite...

Comment: @LeeMosher you're right, thanks for pointing that out, I've just edited the post.

Comment: To finish, consider the commutator subgroup of $N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the hints given in the comment section, I've been able to solve the problem, and I'm posting here the solution for any future reference.

For $(3)$, if there was $M \leq N\,,\,M\neq N$ normal in $G$,  it would mean that $h^{-1}mh \in M$ for every $h \in H$ and $m \in M$. But since $N$ is divided in only two orbits, it exists $x \in H$ such that $x^{-1}mx=n\,,\,n\in N - M$.

For $(2)$, I know that $|N|=p^\alpha$, and that there exists a normal subgroup of $X \leq N$ that has order $p^{\alpha-1}$, meaning that $N/X$ is abelian and $N' \leq X$. But $N'$ is characteristic in $N$, so for $(3)$ it must be trivial $\Rightarrow N$ is abelian.

Comment: You can also prove it considering that the center of $N$ is non trivial, and since it is characteristic in $N$ it must be normal in $G$